# Return result from Async Method within a Sync method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, caliburn.micro

In my application I have an async Save() method, of type `Task<bool>` that via the bool will signal if the save was successfull. All kinds of stuff can happen in the Save(), it calls through another layer where exceptions are handled, possible dialogs shown, etc, but that doesn't matter, all I care about is the bool result.

Now I have to call this method from within a non-async method (which is an override from a used framework, so I cannot just make it async)

The code looks a bit like :

```
public override void SynchronousMethodFromFramework()
{
    bool result = false;
    Task.Run(async () => result = await Save());
    return result;
}
```

The problem is, that the result is returned BEFORE the Save is finished (thus always false).
How can it solve this ? I've tried the Task.WaitAll(), the .Result, the .ConfigureAwaiter(false) but everything I do just seems to completely freeze my application.

A bit more info :

The used WPF framework is Caliburn.Micro. My MainviewModel is a `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive`that conducts multiple viewmodels in a Tabcontrol. Each ViewModel is some sort of edit screen. 
When the end user closes the application (via the right top red X ) I want to iterate over all Tabs to see if they have pending changes.
Code of the mainviewmodel :

```
 public override void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
    {
        //for each tab, go to it and try to close it. 
        //If pending changes and close is not succeeded (eg, user cancels), abort aplication close
        bool canclose = false;
        Action<bool> result = b => canclose = b;
        for (int i = Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var screen = Items[i];
            screen.CanClose(result);
            if (!canclose)
            {
                callback(false);
                return;
            }

        }
        callback(true);
    }
```

Code in my "Edit"-ViewModels:

```
    private async Task<bool> SavePendingChanges()
    {
        if (!Entity.HasDirtyContents())
            return true;
        bool? dialogResult = DialogProvider.ShowMessageBox("Save changes",
            "There are pending changes, do you want to save them ?", MsgBoxButton.YesNoCancel);
        if (dialogResult == null)
            return false;//user cancelled 
        if (dialogResult == false)
            return true;//user doesn't want to save, but continue
        //try to save; if save failed => return false
        return await (Save());
    }

    public override void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
    {
        var task = SavePendingChanges();
        task.Wait();
        bool result = task.Result;
        callback(result);
    }
```

The "CanClose" is a CM-provided non-async framework method ...

Comment: google is your friend: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx. Just do create a variable out of your task and `.Wait()` for it.

Comment: If you block a method on the UI thread then the UI freezes. That's pretty fundamental, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: As mentioned, I've tried that and i completely hangs the application. I suspect that is because somewhere down the chainof the Save() method, a variable "IsBusy" is set that is databound to the visibility of a WPF UI control, a "BizzySpinner" to indicate something is going on.

Comment: OK, I should have said this right away: You need to provide more details. If you want to unfreeze the UI you cannot block that thread. In order to recommend something you need to give more context.

Comment: ok i'll edit the OP to make it more clear

Comment: Why don't you just do: public override async void SynchronousMethodFromFramework() ? I don't remember if async should be before or after override. You should be able to do it even though it's overridden method. Check this.

Comment: Isn't possible to keep the saved/unsaved state of each tab in a more accessible location? Then you could drastically improve the speed of Close action if the core code would just call, supposedly, a `Dictionary<Tab, Status>.Any(pair => pair.Value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *proper* solution is to make `SynchronousMethodFromFramework` asynchronous, either by having it return `Task` or using something like [deferrals](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) (as I describe on my blog). So most definitely *make your needs known* to the framework author(s).

In the meantime, you can hack around it using [one of the hacks from my article on `async` brownfield development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

---

The easiest solution is to make your `Save` method a purely background method - after all, if it is running as a background task, it shouldn't be "reaching into" the UI thread with any updates. If your code calls `Save` in a couple of places - once for a "regular" save and then this other "last chance synchronous only" save - then you can use `IProgress<T>` to update the UI instead of directly accessing ViewModel properties and/or using `Dispatcher`. If your code only calls `Save` here, then just rip out all the UI updates completely.

If you can make `Save` a truly background operation, then you can just block:

```
return Task.Run(() => Save()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

---

But if you can't do that (I assume you've already considered it and rejected it), then you can invoke some serious Dark Magic to bend the runtime to your will. That is, use a Nested Message Loop (a registered trademark of Lucifer Enterprises).

> Developer General's warning: Nested message loops are evil. Evil, evil, evil! Side effects include insanity and death. It is entirely likely that a future maintainer of this code will become violent and hunt you down.

It's been quite a while since I've done a nested message loop in WPF, but I believe this should do the trick:

```
private async Task<bool> EvilSaveAsync(DispatcherFrame frame)
{
  try
  {
    return await Task.Run(() => Save());
  }
  finally
  {
    frame.Continue = false;
  }
}

public override void SynchronousMethodFromFramework()
{
  var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
  var task = EvilSaveAsync(frame);
  Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
  return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stephen Cleary for the answer, but in the meantime, I've also found a solution which seems to be working in all the scenario's I've tried (open multiple tabs, some had no changes, some had changes, and others had changes with optimistic concurrency exceptions that trigger their own workflow, opening dialogs to solve those). And all scenario's worked, so I wonder if it's a good solution or if I'm overlooking something or doing some horrible hack ?

My approach:

Since the problem is the CanClose non-sync method in the CM-framework (actually, the problem there is the callback action),  I've rerouted it in my own ViewModelbase as this :

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : IScreen
{
        //sealed so the users of the viewmodelbase cannot accidentally override it
        public async override sealed void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
        {
            callback(await CanClose());
        }

        //default implementation is always closable
        public async virtual Task<bool> CanClose()
        {
            return true;
        }

}
```

So all "CanClose" from the framework is now rerouted thorugh my own async CanClose method of type Task (notice the "async" on this override - thank you for the hint)

Then in the MainViewmodel which conducts the tabs, my own async CanClose is overridden as :

```
 public async override Task<bool> CanClose()
    {
        for (int i = Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var screen = Items[i] as ViewModelBase;
            var canclose = await screen.CanClose();
            if (!canclose) return false;
            Items.Remove(screen);//remove it from the tabs so it's not visible anymore
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and ultimately, in my EditViewmodels, I've overridden the CanClose as :

```
  public override async Task<bool> CanClose()
    {
        return await SavePendingChanges();
    }

   public async Task<bool> SavePendingChanges()
        {
            if (!Entity.HasDirtyContents())
                return true;
            bool? dialogResult = DialogProvider.ShowMessageBox("Save changes",
                "There are pending changes, do you want to save them ?", MsgBoxButton.YesNoCancel);
            if (dialogResult == null)
                return false;//user cancelled 
            if (dialogResult == false)
                return true;//user doesn't want to save, but continue
            //try to save; if save failed => return false
            return await Save();
        }
```